# modalPresentationStyle not updating the data

Tags: ios, swift

The below code can show the ratings screen using modal or i can push it. if i use modal i can see the animation effect and not in pushed controller method, the animation are defined in a view class separately, but in case of pushed i can see the ratings gets updated instantly but not in modal presentation.

what can be the reason? the code i use to get back after updating the ratings is also below this

How can i update the ratings as well as show the animations effects using either modal or pushed?

why are they behaving differently and not doing both tasks of showing animations and updating the views, but only doing one each?

Is there any limitation as to what modal can do and what push can do, why pushed controller refuses to animates the view? the animations are being defined in separate view class, while the modal animates them perfectly well, but it then refuse to update the new ratings when i show the detail view again.

Code to push controller

```
@objc func gotoRatings() {
      let rateDetailView = RatingsViewController()
     rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant
      rateDetailView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
      present(rateDetailView, animated: true, completion: nil)
       //     rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant
      
      //  navigationController?.pushViewController(rateDetailView, animated: true)
    }
```

Code to add ratings

```
@objc func addRatings(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let detailReturn = DetailViewController()
        if let rating = sender.titleLabel?.text {
         self.restaurant.rating = rating
          if let appDelegat = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            appDelegat.saveContext()
          }
        }
        
        
       detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant
     
   //   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: false)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

UPDATES

The modal view  is basically an extension of current view hence it has no back button.

The push controller can not have custom actions, but is used for the case when a controller is pushed on top of stack with all views , updated.

In my case i want a combination of both, so may be i will need to push the view and then make animations on the control page rather then view page as the view's animations will not get pushed

UPDATED CODE- the class where protocol is defined

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol RatingsPresentation: class {
    func defineTheratings(_ ratings: String)
}

class RatingsViewController: UIViewController, RatingsPresentation {
    func defineTheratings(_ ratings: String) {
     print("ratings seleced \(ratings)")
   let detailReturn = DetailViewController()
           self.restaurant.rating = ratings
           if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
               appDelegate.saveContext()
           }
    


    if  self.presentingViewController  != nil {
               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       
           }
           else {
                detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant
            
            //   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: true)
           }
}

    var restaurant: Restaurant!
    var rates = RatingsView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(rates.view)
        //Delegates
      
        // set the rating delegate
        rates.ratingDelegate = self
        //
        if let restaurantImage = restaurant.image {
            
            rates.bkgImageView.image = UIImage(data: restaurantImage as Data)
        }
        
        rates.crossBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeRatings), for: .touchUpInside)
  
        
        let animateCross = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1000, y: 0)
        rates.crossBtn.transform = animateCross
  
    }
    
    @objc func closeRatings() {
    
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
     
    }

}
```

The View for ratings

```
import UIKit

class RatingsView: UIViewController {
    
    var bkgImageView = UIImageView()
    var crossBtn = UIButton()
    var btnCollection: [UIButton] = []
    weak var ratingDelegate: RatingsPresentation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let ratings: [String] = ["cool", "happy","love", "sad", "angry"]
        
        let animationBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        let visualBlurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: animationBlur)
        
        
        
        
        // add elements to self
        view.addSubview(bkgImageView)
        view.addSubview(visualBlurView)
        
        bkgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        visualBlurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bkgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bkgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bkgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bkgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // constrain visualBlurView to all 4 sides
        visualBlurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        visualBlurView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        visualBlurView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        visualBlurView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        bkgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //Add stackView
        
        let stackEmoji = UIStackView()
        stackEmoji.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        stackEmoji.axis = .vertical
        stackEmoji.spacing = 5
        stackEmoji.distribution = .fill
        stackEmoji.alignment = .top
        
        let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 28)
        let fontM = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
        
        ratings.forEach { (btn) in
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle(btn, for: .normal)
            b.titleLabel?.font = fontM.scaledFont(for: font!)
            b.setImage(UIImage(named: btn), for: .normal)
            stackEmoji.addArrangedSubview(b)
            btnCollection.append(b)
            
            //btn animation
            let sizeAnimation = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
            let positionAnimation = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1000, y: 0)
            let combinedAninaton = sizeAnimation.concatenating(positionAnimation)
            b.transform = combinedAninaton
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(stackEmoji)
        
        stackEmoji.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackEmoji.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
//          if let img = UIImage(named: "cross") {
//            crossBtn.setImage(img, for: [])
//              }
        
        crossBtn.setTitle("X", for: [])
        crossBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        crossBtn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
        crossBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 44, weight: .bold)
        view.addSubview(crossBtn)
        
        
        crossBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        crossBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
        crossBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
        
       

    }
    
  
    
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      //  print(sender.titleLabel?.text)
        guard let t = sender.titleLabel?.text else {
            return
        }
        
        ratingDelegate?.defineTheratings(t)
                 
    }
   

}
```

latest updates

```
func defineTheratings(_ ratings: String) {
         print("ratings seleced \(ratings)")
        
        if  self.presentingViewController  != nil {
                 
                         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                 
                     }
                     else {
                       //   detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant
                      
                         self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                    //  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: true)
                     }
        
          self.restaurant.rating = ratings
        
        
        
     
             
               if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                 
                   appDelegate.saveContext()
               
               }
        
    
 
        let detailReturn = DetailViewController()
        
        
        detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: true)
        
        
    }
```

code to reach ratings controller

```
let rateDetailView = RatingsViewController() 
rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant 
rateDetailView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   present(rateDetailView, animated: true, completion: nil)





override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let  restaurantRating = restaurant.rating {

                                     detailView.ratingsIcon.image = UIImage(named: restaurantRating)
                  let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)
                         self.detailView.ratingsIcon.transform = scaleTransform
                         self.detailView.ratingsIcon.alpha = 0


                                 }
        
       
          
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
                 
                 self.detailView.ratingsIcon.alpha = 1
                 self.detailView.ratingsIcon.transform = .identity
             }, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the Protocol / Delegate pattern.

Create a custom `protocol`:

```
protocol RatingSelectedDelegate: class {
    func didSelectRating(_ rating: String)
}
```

Make your class that will either push or present the ratings controller `conform` to the delegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, RatingSelectedDelegate {

    func didSelectRating(_ rating: String) {
        // update your UI and data source
        // either pop or dismiss the ratings controller
    }
}
```

In your ratings controller, add a delegate var:

```
class RatingsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var ratingDelegate: RatingSelectedDelegate?
    
}
```

In your main class, set the delegate when you instantiate the ratings controller:

```
    // instantiate Ratings View Controller
    let vc = RatingsViewController()
    // set the rating delegate
    vc.ratingDelegate = self
```

Then, in your ratings controller, when a rating is selected, tell the delegate:

```
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        
        // unwrap the button's current title
        guard let t = sender.currentTitle else {
            return
        }
        
        // tell the delegate a rating was selected
        ratingDelegate?.didSelectRating(t)
    }
```

Here it is all together...

- Assign `@IBAction func pushToRatings()` to a button to see the "push" mode.
- Assign `@IBAction func presentRatings()` to a button to see the "present" mode.

This example has a `RatingsViewController` with 6 buttons labeled "1" thru "6" in a vertical stack:

```
protocol RatingSelectedDelegate: class {
    func didSelectRating(_ rating: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, RatingSelectedDelegate {
    
    @IBAction func pushToRatings(_ sender: Any) {
        // instantiate Ratings View Controller
        let vc = RatingsViewController()
        // set the rating delegate
        vc.ratingDelegate = self
        // push it
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func presentRatings(_ sender: Any) {
        // instantiate Ratings View Controller
        let vc = RatingsViewController()
        // set the rating delegate
        vc.ratingDelegate = self
        // full screen modal
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        // present it
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func didSelectRating(_ rating: String) {
        
        // for debugging
        print("Rating selected: \(rating)")

        // update your data
        self.restaurant.rating = rating
        if let appDelegat = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
            appDelegat.saveContext()
        }

        // update your UI with the newly selected rating, e.g.
        // someLabel.text = rating

        // if we have a presentedViewController
        //  dismiss it
        // else
        //  pop it off the stack
        
        if self.presentedViewController != nil {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}

class RatingsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var ratingDelegate: RatingSelectedDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].forEach{ v in
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle("\(v)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
            b.backgroundColor = .red
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
    }
    
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        
        // unwrap the button's current title
        guard let t = sender.currentTitle else {
            return
        }
        
        // tell the delegate a rating was selected
        ratingDelegate?.didSelectRating(t)
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** to try and answer your comment...

You only give little pieces of information in your questions, so I'm going to try to offer you help - but without seeing your actual code or getting a full, clear description, this may not completely work. Hopefully, if you follow the comments, it will start to make sense:

```
func defineTheratings(_ ratings: String) {

    print("ratings seleced \(ratings)")

    // if the RatingsView was presented, dismiss it
    //  otherwise, it was pushed, so pop it
    if  self.presentingViewController  != nil {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    // if the "cross button" was tapped, you aren't getting back a
    //  "selected rating" -- so check for that here and, I'm guessing,
    //  do NOT move on to your DetailViewController
    
    if ratings == "X" { // or whatever you are sending for the cross button
        // no rating was selected, so we're done
        return
    }
    
    // the cross button was not tapped, which means we got a rating,
    //  and we want to show the detail view
    
    // update this variable
    self.restaurant.rating = ratings

    // I'm guessing you're using this to update saved data?
    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }

    // instantiate your Detail VC
    let detailReturn = DetailViewController()
    
    // set the property
    detailReturn.restaurant = restaurant

    // I'm guessing you're in a navigation controller, so
    //  push to the detail vc
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailReturn, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: the problem of not being able to update the emoji when presenting modally, remain, everything works perfectly but when i use modal presentation then the update in database is not reflected on detail view emoji, kindly guide, i have uploaded the current working code, works fine with push , closes with modal but does not change the emoji immediately, it does get updated in database but not on view

Comment: @multiverse - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: thanks, i made the changes but the original issue of not being able to instantly update the emoji rating remains, every thing works well if the view is pushed, i have published all the code of 2 main files, the only code not published is this -  let rateDetailView = RatingsViewController()
           rateDetailView.restaurant = restaurant
           rateDetailView.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
           present(rateDetailView, animated: true, completion: nil) , which is how i move from details view by clicking the ratings buttons, added it to my question end as well

Comment: @multiverse - I think you need to focus on one task at a time. It is not at all clear what you mean by *"instantly update the emoji rating"*. What is your UI flow? Are you looking at a list of Restaurants? And do you tap one to see a Details VC? And the Details VC shows the current rating? And you tap something to show your Ratings Selection VC? And when you dismiss that you want to update the "current rating" in the Details VC? Or some other flow altogether?

Comment: 1) I click the ratings button on restaurants detail page which contains info on hotel 2) I go to ratings controller using either modal or push 3) The ratings page with 5 emojis appear 4) I click an emoji and that ratings page is dismissed 5) Now i am back at detail page with new emoji, say before it was angry now its cool . Problem with modal this update does not take place, solution - currently i am making changes in viewWillAppear of detailView, as delegate protocol approach did not work, if only there was an option to send all files i would, thanks

Comment: *"if only there was an option to send all files"* ... putting your project on GitHub is one way. If you look at my answer - *before the edit* - in the `didSelectRating()` function I have a comment: `// update your UI with the newly selected rating, e.g. // someLabel.text = rating` ... ***That*** is where you could do something like `currentRatingEmojiImageView.image = UIImage(named: rating)`. It wouldn't matter whether you're returning from a pushed VC or dismissing a presented VC.

Comment: i have added the viewWillAppear code i am using to get it done in my question, in the DetailViewController, attempts to try and add the ratings etc even in the dismiss function completion as closure have not worked for me , i must be doing some thing wrong, other then this viewWillAppear addition code other code remains same

Comment: @multiverse - it is *really* tough when we only get drips-and-drabs instead of ***complete*** code, descriptions, and questions. But, because this is so fundamental, I put this together - give it a look and see if you can follow what it's doing: https://github.com/DonMag/CoreDataRatings

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use RxSwift and the PublishSubject public/private broadcast pattern. All you need to do is create a public variable on your vc that you are accessing that is observable and have a private publish subject inside your other vc the you can you use to call updates on and it will be bound to the public variable that you can observe in the original vc. Don't forget to use share() if you look into this.